# What is the point of prospective buyers asking me to trade my Unusual to a friend first?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Recently, I unboxed a new Unusual Hat, and a couple of people have tried doing this to me:

> Never tell your password to anyone.
>
> ME.: hello
>
> THEM: hey
>
> THEM: how much for your unusuals in buds or keys?
>
> ME: for the Janesary (with new effect) I was looking for around 2.5 buds
>
> THEM: okay can you wait 5minutes ? il lget the buds first
>
> ME: k
>
> THEM: can i ask a rpoof before i get the buds?
>
> ME: ?
>
> THEM: do you have a trusted friend?
>
> ME: you are the second person to ask this. I dont feel like doing this so I dont add more IDs to the list
>
> THEM: can we use your trustred friend to hold your items until i get the buds?
>
> ME: why does it matter
>
> THEM: coz ive done this before i buy the items then they cancel our agreement.
>
> ME: i dont have anyone else who wants to buy it
>
> THEM: you can trade to your friend now and tell him dont give to me unless i get the buds
>
> ME: i dont plan on doing that. I don't want to add more ids to the main list
>
> THEM: so whats the name of your friend?
>
> ME: his username is IDon'tPlanOnDoingThat
>
> THEM: k
>
> ***UPDATE***
>
> THEM:?
>
> ME: ?
>
> THEM: so you got a friend now?

(I will update that if he adds more).

What does this try to accomplish? I don't understand at all, but I don't plan on doing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're trying to scam you.

It's a common scam tactic to try to impersonate one of your friends (name and avatar) to give the unusual to it, at which point they have the unusual and run off with it.

Usually, their alt account is already on your friends list (previously traded with you).

Comment: The disadvantages of unboxing something nice. I was thinking, what would trading to a friend do to help them? I could just tell my friend to not trade the item to them. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: They're hoping your "friend" is the extra person on your friends list.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Because you are being scammed, you should report the scammer (posting the scammers username will let us report him as well).